# Asymptote message on GNU Emacs using TeX Live 2018

Tags: emacs, asymptote

I use GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (on Windows 10) for my work with LaTeX and friends,
which include working with Asymptote files, using the mode asy-mode.

Using TeX Live 2017, I compile asymptote files without any problems, but using TeX Live 2018, with the file

```
import three;
triple v1=(1,0,0);
draw(v1);
```

and doing ``` asy -vv -V -wait ``file'' ``` I get

```
freeglut (asy): fghInitialize: CreateDC failed, Screen size info may be incorrect
This is quite likely caused by a bad '-display' parameter
```

If I compile the same file from the command line I don't get this message.

Any help on understanding this and find the true culprit will be
appreciated.

Comment: I just updated to TeXLive 2018 on MacOS and don't have a problem.

Comment: I get the same message (Windows 7, latest Asymptote version). But I don't see any problem in the rendering.

Answer (score 1):

The freeglut call to CreateDC will use the command line parameter -display or it will use the DISPLAY environment variable if it exists. An invalid value will cause this failure. If you are not passing a -display parameter then check the value of DISPLAY in your environment variables. My git bash shell had the DISPLAY environment variable set to, "needs-to-be-defined", which caused the failure. Either change the variable so that DISPLAY=DISPLAY or remove the environment variable so that the screen metrics are obtained by the default method within freeglut.